# Fetching data with redux from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch from Firebase some data using redux and display them with react within a material table component. The data are received but after the data arrived I receive this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I think that the payload is sent before that all the data to be received from firebase. Still, I am using await on this and I don't understand where I am getting wrong.

```
export const fetchReviews = () => async (dispatch) => {

const reviewsCollectionRef = db.collection('reviews');
let reviews = [];
 await reviewsCollectionRef .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    reviews.push(doc.data());
  
}); }).then(() =>   dispatch({
type: FETCH_DATA_FROM_FIREBASE,
payload: reviews
}));
```

Comment: I tired the code of @Praveen Dass 's answer and it works as expected for me. Maybe the issue is that your component is accessing the data when it still hasn't been fetched.
Could you share the code that calls the `fetchReviews()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
export const fetchReviews = () => async (dispatch) => {
  let reviews = [];
  //perform asynchronous tasks
  await db.collection('reviews').get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      reviews.push(doc.data());
    })       
  });
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_DATA_FROM_FIREBASE,
    payload: reviews
  });
}
```

Comment: I receive the error before the actual rendering within the component. The error is triggered when the logger is trying to log the payload.

Comment: Same result unfortunetly.

Comment: The issue was caused by a mistake made by me while I was trying to connect the component to the redux store. Thank you for your answer.